# How is it possible to make rebuild run a method in my project?

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application, that when started in its constructor it generates some classes on the fly.
Is there a way which i can use, so that when i build or rebuild the project, some specific method gets called and thus generating my files without running the whole application?

Comment: How are you generating the classes?  Is this something that can be done at compile-time with something like T4 templates instead of at run-time in code?  It's generally a good idea to separate *building* an application from *running* an application.

Comment: yes it can be done using T4 templates, but due to the lack of my knowledge on T4 templates, i am using the old school way! for generating the classes using sting.Format and etc

Comment: If you want to keep generating your application code *from* application code then I would recommend creating two separate applications.  Application A would be a small utility which simply generates the code files used by Application B.  The build process for Application B wouldn't care where those files came from, just that they're present.  It would likely be easier in the long run to use Visual Studio functionality to generate the code, so you can just right-click on a template and generate.  But if you want to use code, it should at least be a separate application.

Comment: Thank you very much David, i appreciate your time and help;)